# passing value from xcode to javascript

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode

i m using google api v3 in my apps. to find direction, i need to pass my current location & destination to java script. google api v3 use java script to use map functionalities.

i use following to pass variable. but did not work.

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Handler.method(%@);", str]];
```

how can i pass variable from obj c to javascript..???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i pass value to a native html page from my web view application through URL

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?bob=123&frank=321&tom=213", base]];

NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webView loadRequest:req];
```

The value has been passed to html page and javascript with the URL
At Javascript use the following function to get value

```
function gup( name )
{
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
    if( results == null )
        return "";
    else
        return results[1];
```

}

now call this function with parameter name of the value

```
var userLat=(gup( 'bob' ));
```

this will return the value 123

hope this helps.....:)